# Why doesn't [IO.File]::GetAttributes( "File.Dat" ) work in Powershell

Tags: .net, powershell

Why doesn't `[IO.File]::GetAttributes( "File.Dat" )` work in Powershell?

I am able to see `file.dat` (as an example) when I use `get-item "file.dat"`.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this might be happening is because if you provide a relative path to `[IO.File]::GetAttributes()` it is interpreted relative to the result of `[IO.Directory]::GetCurrentDirectory()`

> Relative path information is interpreted as relative to the current working directory. To obtain the current working directory, see GetCurrentDirectory.

To get around this you can provide the full path to the file by going:

```
[IO.File]::GetAttributes((gci ".\path\to\file.txt").FullName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Typically you will want to post any error messages you're receiving, and more specific information. For example:

- What folder is `file.dat` in?
- What PowerShell context (PSDrive) are you launching the command from?
- What error are you getting?
- What result are you expecting?

That being said, have you tried the fully qualified path to the file?

```
[System.IO.File]::GetAttributes("c:\path\to\file.dat");
```

This command seems to work perfectly fine for me:

```
[System.IO.File]::GetAttributes("c:\windows\system32\ipconfig.exe");
```

Comment: Thank you.  I've really enjoyed this site and I appreciate your help.  As a beginner in all of this (site and coding), I hope to make better posts with information that is more useful when asking a question.